# Clarification of Appeal Procedure

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure, federal-courts, appeal

If a party were suing under something like civil rights claims and a judge ordered the dismissal of the parties state claims while allowing the federal civil rights claims, how could one go about an appeal with regards to supersedeas bonds and perfecting the appeal?

How could a 'motion to stay pending an appeal and approval of supersedeas bond' affect the time a party could have to perfect an appeal?  Or, could the filing of the 'stay' affect the time to perfect an appeal?

Could a party attach 'bond' papers to the motion to stay pending approval of supersedeas bond?

After first contacting a certified and approved bonding company how long could it take under normal circumstanced to get a bond?

If a party is appealing an order how is the amount of appeal set?

The rules seem to offer questions in with their answers.

Comment: The civil law tag pertains to the legal systems found in continental Europe. I changed it to civil procedure and added a federal courts tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a party were suing under something like civil rights claims and a
>   judge ordered the dismissal of the parties state claims while allowing
>   the federal civil rights claims, how could one go about an appeal with
>   regards to supersedeas bonds and perfecting the appeal?

You couldn't appeal the decision until the federal civil rights claim remaining was resolved because the dismissal is an interlocutory order which is subject to appeal only in narrow circumstances that probably don't apply in this case. When there was a final order on all of the outstanding claims, you could then appeal both the dismissal of the state claims as well as any issue you were dissatisfied with under the federal claim if you felt the appeal was worth it and had merit at that point.